# How to prevent the automatic updates between google-sheets when using IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, synchronization, google-sheets-formula

I got a google-sheet-1 reading data from an other google-sheet-2.
The data of google-sheet-2 runs on a scheduler.
In my google-sheet-1 the user enter a new line with the date of the day and IMPORTRANGE get the data from google-sheet-2 and add it to the new line.
My problem is that IMPORTRANGE syncs all lines of google-sheet-1 to the latest values of google-sheet-2. I would like to read the value only once and break the automatic update... Is this possible or am I thinking about it the wrong way...

Comment: You do not have to work with importrange, you have to copy as values the data. Give us a  Minimal Reproducible Example

Comment: It is possible, but requires writing a script rather than using stock Sheet functions.

Comment: I used apps scripts instead of IMPORTRANGE Thanks mate @Mattking